# How to query count of unique features in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, group-by, google-sheets-formula, pivot-table

I have this table:

```
Name    | Age
Ann     | adult
Ann     | adult
Andrew  | adult
Mike    | adult
Ann     | teenager
John    | teenager
John    | teenager
```

I want this output:

```
Age      | count Name (distinct Names)
adult    |  3
teenager |  2
```

Unfortunately, I can't go further then this formula:

```
=QUERY(table; "select B, count(A) group by B"; 1)
```

where the 'table' is the named range with input data. And it gives me this:

```
Age      | count Name
adult    |  4
teenager |  3
```

I need something like:

```
=QUERY(table; "select B, count(unique(A)) group by A"; 1)
```

which obviously doesn't work.

So, how can I achieve my target output with querying?

I know, I can do that with pivot tables with countunique function, but I want to go without pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be `QUERY` + `UNIQUE`:

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(A2:B),"SELECT Col2, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col2")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(UNIQUE({B:B, B:B & A:A, A:A}), "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY COUNT(Col1) DESC LABEL COUNT(Col1)'count Name'", 1))
```

**After**

[image: after using the query]

**Explanation**

The formula makes use of the following functions:

- `ARRAYFORMULA`
- `UNIQUE`
- `QUERY`

In order to find the unique values, the `UNIQUE` is used for the range needed for the query (`A:B`) such that the sorting and counting is done on this range. The `LABEL` is used as well in order to set the header name for the resulted column.

#### Reference

- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275);
- [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198);
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343).